# How to find Jordan Basis and Jordan Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

I need to find the Jordan Normal form $J$ and a matrix $S$ such that $J = S^{-1} AS$.

The matrix is 
$$
M = \left(
\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{matrix} \right)
$$

This matrix is over the finite field $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

I have found the characteristic polynomial.  It is $x^4$, so the only eigenvalue is $x = 0$.  I found two linearly independent eigenvectors.

$$
v_1 =\left(
\begin{matrix} 
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)\qquad
v_2 = \left(
\begin{matrix} 
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

So I need two more vectors to form the matrix $S$.  My first thought was two find 2 generalized eigenvectors, but since there are 2 eigenvectors, I am not sure how to do this.  Is this the only way to go?  Or is there another way of getting the 2 vectors that I need?

Also, when I have 4 vectors, how do I know which order to put them in the matrix $S$?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! You have to find vectors $w_1, w_2$ such that $\;Mw_1=v_1$, $\;Mw_2=v_2$. In the basis $\mathcal J=(v_1, w_1,v_2,w_2)$ the matrix will have the Jordan form
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$